# terraform config for Azure Stack

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform

Is it possible to provide a value in the form of a URL for the "environment" variable, in order to deploy to Azure Stack?

Right now, the only documented supported values seem to be: Public, Government, Germany and China.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, terraform does not support Azure Stack. Please refer to this [feedback](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7299) on GitHub. Also you could check providers that terraform support, please refer to this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Walter. The Terraform site mentions Azure Stack. Weird !
https://www.hashicorp.com/azure/

Comment: @Vinny I think Terraform will support Azure Stack, but currently, it does not support this.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the timeline on this ? Or if not, who does ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the timeline. Maybe you could check this [link](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13). The issue is open, if terraform supports Azure Stack, the issue will close.

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

Azure Stack support has now been released as of 20th June 2018: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurestack/index.html